# Can't open VCD Video on iMac (OX 10.10.4)

Tags: video, optical-drive

Soooo, we have a couple educational VCDs from Taiwan.  Upon insertion, they mount as 2 volumes, Audio CD and VIDEODISC.  A quick Google said to browse to VIDEODISC/MPEGAV and play the DAT files there, which were essentially MPG files with extra (unspecified) data.  But, on both discs *every* .DAT file has an i/o error.  It's disc/OS interaction level - Finder won't copy the files, and a Disk Image creation failed (Error message: Invalid Argument), and Disk Utility kind of hangs at exit.

I don't know well the discs were taken care of, so I could see maybe one or two files that would have corruption, but not issues with every .DAT file (70+ files across 2 discs). They're Windows formatted volumes (the VIDEODISC volume has a Windows VCD player executable) but that never was an issue before.  The fact that Disk Utility not only decides not to copy, but seems very confused in general.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you try to open them with VLC player, by Starting the VLC then open file?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD yes, but there's a core I/o error I mentioned. It can't even read the file much less decode and play

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you can not open that file in the VLC player? if so what error does it gives?